# Angular Material cannot be loaded in a new module

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I created an angular material module (like a core module).

```js
import { NgModule} from '@angular
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

And I want to add this module to another module:

```js
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import { TestModuleRoutingModule } from './test-module-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/';
import { ModuleIntTestComponent } from './module-int-test/module-int-test.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TestModuleRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [ModuleIntTestComponent],
})
export class TestModuleModule { }
```

Then inside the **ModuleIntTestComponent** i want to use the angular material checkbox.

```html
<p>module-int-test works!</p>
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Checked</mat-checkbox>
```

but I get the following error:

```
***ERROR in src/app/test-module/module-int-test/module-int-test.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-checkbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3 <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Checked</mat-checkbox>

 src/app/test-module/module-int-test/module-int-test.component.ts:6:16
   6   templateUrl: './module-int-test.component.html',
   Error occurs in the template of component ModuleIntTestComponent.***
```

What is missing or what is wrong?

I cannot understand.

Note: If I add my MaterialModule to the AppModule I can use without any issue the Material Checkbox in any component of the AppModule.

Comment: This looks very correct to me, but I sometimes struggle with Module changes not being picked up by "ng serve". Have you tried restarting your IDE or computer?

Comment: Yes the code was correct. I put the wrong code in the module loading on the app routing. Passing from angular 5 to 9 the lazy loading changed and I made this mistake, with the new code everything is working fine;)

Comment: just if someone needs in the future:    {
    path: 'moduleint',
    loadChildren: () => import('./test-module/test-module.module')
      .then(mod => mod.TestModuleModule)
  }

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
In MaterialModule,

```
export class MaterialModule { 
 static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
   ngModule: MaterialModule
 };
}
```

}

while importing the MaterialModule in another module use this.

```
import:[
  MaterialModule.forRoot()
],
export:[
 MaterialModule
]
```

Hope this will helpful

Comment: I put the wrong code in the module loading on the app routing. Passing from angular 5 to 9 the lazy loading changed and I made this mistake, with the new code everything is working fine;)

Comment: ohh..ok 
there is some difference in routing from angular 8. (Y)